# Extract 2 PDF images and combine on one PDF page

Tags: imagemagick-convert

I have two scanned PDF pages with miscellaneous writings all around.  There are two main segments in the middle of both pages that I want to extract and then place onto one page as a PDF image.

> ```
> -------
> |      |
> | xxx  |
> | xxx  |
> |      |
> --------
> ```

I need to extract just the middle portions marked by x's, then place those images one above the other to make a new PDF page.  Because of the miscellaneous markings all around, I need to get as close as possible to the text boxes.  The page size from identify is 612x786.  If I know the best command to use, I can experiment to get as close as possible.  I have no prior experience with ImageMagick and need to get this done as quickly as possible.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
convert in1.pdf -crop widthxheight+woffset+hoffset! out1.pdf
convert in2.pdf -crop widthxheight+woffset+hoffset! out2.pdf
convert out1.pdf out2.pdf -append out3.pdf
```

The '!' sets the new canvas size to the widthxheight size.